# Instanced Rendering of height map applied terrain mesh/geometry

Tags: three.js, game-development, terrain

I am working in three.js to make terrain from the heightmap data that i have in json file. I now have a chunk of mesh which add up to make a complete terrain but since multiple chunk make multiple draw call which i believe is expensive and making my system very slow.

This is my code:

https://github.com/pravinpoudel/three.js-boilerplate/blob/main/src/client/terrain.ts

This is my terrain after i apply the heightmap and is of size 4104x1856 madeup from chunk of size (256, 256)

[image]

I checked the documentation and example of instanced rendering in three.js but all ask for same geometry but in my case i have deformed the y value of each vertex according to the heightmap data from elevation json file.

I believe that i can make it perform better with instanced rendering but i dont know how can i implement that with each geometry in the chunk have altered y value.

Moreover, is there anything more you can suggest?

I am learning a lot from this group and i believe that i can get more insight from here.

Thank you everyone for being here and helping people like me !!

Comment: Please show us your code. There are many ways to achieve what you're describing, some more performant than others. It's impossible to tell which approach you've taken without demonstrating your code. It would be best if you could add a working example through https://jsfiddle.net or a code snippet. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you @Marquizzo, this is my code in this repo, 

https://github.com/pravinpoudel/three.js-boilerplate/blob/main/src/client/terrain.ts

Comment: do you still believe that jsfiddle would be more effective? if so i will create one and again thank you so much